Create Common generic Controller and Repository in Symfony 6
We are migrating from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 6.4 and we are rewriting the necessary code required to upgrade to new version. In our older version we have common repository and controller to perform the generic task which are called from almost every repository & controller respectively. In common controller we are extending Controller"class CommonController extends Controller" and in the common repository we are extending Entity Repository "class CommonRepository extends EntityRepository". In all the other repository/contollers we are simply extending the common Repository/Controller. We have declared under services.yml like the below in older version.
services:
    bundle.repository.common:
        class: Bundle\Repository\CommonRepository
        abstract: true
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
        

But when we are trying to do the same in the new symfony 6.4, we are getting issues. The extend implementation remains the same and below is the code to add from services.yml in the new symfony:
Bundle\Repository\CommonRepository:
    abstract:  true
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    calls:
        - setLogger: ['@logger']
        

After this we are getting error as
InvalidArgumentException > LoaderLoadException
Expected to find class "Bundle\Repository\ClrRepository" in file "src\Bundle\Repository\ClrRepository.php" while importing services from resource "../src/Bundle/Repository", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in /config/services.yaml (which is being imported from "src\Kernel.php").
Now I am stuck at this point and any changes I am doing is resulting in error.
I tried to change the setting as per Symfony 6 but not getting the desired result.

this kind of error usually appears when a class is defined in the wrong file or the file has the wrong namespace in it. As far as I can tell, the error message has nothing to do with the CommonRepository but with the ClrRepository instead. the ClrRepository appears to have a path-namespace-mismatch

@Jakumi Thanks for the response. Both the repository are present in the same location. One strange thing I noticed that any repository which is above the CommonRepository is throwing same error. If I change the name and move down CommonRepository then they are working fine.

what do you mean with "above" and "move down"? Usually, symfony will load all classes by default in the source dir - on dev - to build the container definition for auto-wiring. It obviously will fail on the first file that causes a problem. have you tried like ... not defining the classes explicitly in the services.yaml and just trust symfony to do the right thing? also if your base namespace is not App, you should try to do the steps to change that properly.

After lots of searching and checking finally we were able to create the common controller and repository. We did not needed to load the via services, followed the generic structure and was able to achieve it.
